# Jquery Mobile POP Up Capture Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Table with  option to remove a row .

My requirement is that , when clicked on the Remove link , i need to show a Jquery mobile pop up with Yes OR NO  Options , if clicked on Yes only 
the Row Must be deleted or else do nothing

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

This is my code

```
var original = $('table').html();
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
$("#itemdelpopup").popup("open");
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td').addClass('deleteHighlight').animate({
        padding: 0
    }).wrapInner('<div />').children().slideUp(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2EL5R/146/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EL5R/150/) with a working solution.

I just added IDs to the buttons in the popup for being able to capture the click events this way:

```
var original = $('table').html();
var clickedTD;
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
$("#itemdelpopup").popup("open");
   clickedTD=$(this).closest('tr').children('td'); 
});

$("#yes").click(function(event){
    clickedTD.addClass('deleteHighlight').animate({
        padding: 0
    }).wrapInner('<div />').children().slideUp(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});

$("#no").click(function(event){
    alert("the user clicked NO!");
    $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});
```